# I suddenly lost access to my Microsoft Access database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I am using Access on my Mac through parallel desktop. I worked on my database all day until I recently got this error message:

[image]

I am baffled to what could have happened... Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: The message means someone else entered the database, rendering you the inability to make design changes. To see, exit the database and in its folder, see if the [lock file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/966848), `ldb` remains.

Comment: @Parfait Thank you! It was a bizarre problem with parallel. I shut down Windows and everything went back to normal! :D